# Find the limit of a sum of sine products as n approaches infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

What is the best way to tackle the following limit:
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin{\frac{k}{n^2}}\sin{\frac{k}{n}},$$
as well as any similar ones, like these for instance:
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin{\frac{k}{n^2}}\cos{\frac{k}{n}}\quad \text{and} \quad \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2}\cos{\frac{k}{n^2}}\cos{\frac{k}{n}}.$$
Is it a good idea to expand each sum to find a pattern in order to write the formula for its partial sum?
If that can somehow be done, then finding the limit would be trivial.

Perhaps there is a way of expanding the sum as Laurent series at $n=\infty$. Plugging the first sum into *WolframAlpha* yields the following:

$$(\sin(1) - \cos(1)) - \frac{\sin(1)}{2 n} + \frac{7 \sin(1) - 9 \cos(1)}{12 n^2} + \frac{\sin(1)}{12 n^3} + \frac{121 \sin(1) - 205 \cos(1)}{240 n^4} + O((\frac{1}{n})^5).
$$
Removing  all terms with $n$ in the denominator leaves us with the correct result: $\sin{(1)}-\cos{(1)}.$
It would be great to know whether a less cumbersome way of solving such limits exists.

**Thank you in advance for your help!**

Comment: By the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Comment: Simple solution for the first one on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2014866p14138540.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcoming, Claude Leibovici, and for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If you use the classical
$$\sin(a)\sin(b)=\frac 12 \big[\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b)\big]$$ the summand is
$$\frac 12 \Bigg[\cos \left(\frac{k (n-1)}{n^2}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{k (n+1)}{n^2}\right)\Bigg]$$ and you face the problem of the sums of cosines of angles in arithemetic progression and this is well known.

You should end with a simple formula for the partial sum and then for the limit.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be rigorous.
$$x-\frac{x^2}2\space\le\space\sin x \space\le\space x$$
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac k {n^2}\left(1-\frac{k}{2n^2}\right)\sin{\frac{k}{n}}\quad\le\quad
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin{\frac{k}{n^2}}\sin{\frac{k}{n}}\quad\le\quad
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{k}{n^2}}\sin{\frac{k}{n}}$$
$$\therefore\quad\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin{\frac{k}{n^2}}\sin{\frac{k}{n}}\space=\space
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{k}{n^2}}\sin{\frac{k}{n}}$$
Substituting $\frac k n \rightarrow x$, $\frac 1 n \rightarrow dx$,
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{k}{n^2}}\sin{\frac{k}{n}}=\int_0^1x\sin x\space\mathbb dx=\left[\sin x - x \cos x\right]_0^1=\sin 1 - \cos 1
$$